# Long press and single click on button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

How to get button Clicked for single time or Long press on it clicked event?

Comment: what have you tried to find out it? however... you could start here **[UILongPressGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

Comment: Click? You use a mouse do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code

```
//Add Long Press Gesture Reconizer
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 3; //seconds
longPress.delegate = self;
[yourButton addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

//Add button touch
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[yourButton addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
//For touch you can also set selector for button event with Controlevent touchupinside


-(void) handleLongPress : (id)sender
{
   //Long Press done by the user
}

-(void) tapDetected : (id) sender
{
   //Button Tapped by user
}
```

Comment: Click? What is clicking? The mouse?

Comment: Click is considered as touch. I have modified as touch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an NSTimer to measure the duration between the 'touch down inside' and 'touch up inside' events on the button.

You would then define a threshold for a 'long press' and handle the touch up event as a 'long press' if the duration threshold has been passed.

Comment: can you plz put code there no method "touch down inside " its "touch down"